# Is it possible that UIImagePickerController's image has no CGImage value?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, cgimage

I'm trying to reduce force unwrapping in my code but sometimes I also don't want to write `if let` checks if they are not necessary.

I've noticed I have a lot of force unwraps in one specific part of code where users take a picture with their camera or from their phone library and I crop and compress it. This is the process with all force unwraps:

1. I force unwrap image from `imagePickerController(picker: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` function:

   ```
   let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage`
   ```

   I feel pretty safe about this one since I have `imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]`.
2. I use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to crop the image and its first parameter is a `CGImage` which I force unwrap. This is my biggest assumption and although I've never had a crash, I still know it's not safe.

   ```
   let cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(pickedImage.CGImage!, cropRect)
   let croppedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
   ```
3. I use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` that returns `NSData`, but may return `nil` if image has no `CGImageRef`. I force unwrap that too based on my previous assumption.

   ```
   let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 0.85)
   ```
4. I create the result image by force unwrapping again because I assume `jpegData` is not `nil`.

   ```
   let resultImage = UIImage(data: jpegData)!
   ```

TLDR: Is it possible that `UIImagePickerController` returns an image that has no `CGImage`? If yes, I will add a check between steps 1 and 2 to see if there is a `CGImage` value. Can I still safely force unwrap other steps?

Comment: Are you getting data into `pickedImage` object ?

Comment: @CodeChanger all the code I mention above works (so far). I'm just trying to modify it to avoid potential problems in the future. In other words, yes, I'm getting data into pickedImage.

Answer (score 1):

yes, CGImage property of a `UIImage` can be `NULL`.

> If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the value of the property is NULL.

source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624147-cgimage

Answer (score 0):

**UIImage** = Manager of the image (orientation, size, scale. etc.)

**CIImage** = "The recipe", not image in raw, but has the tools to recover it (properties array, the color space, the URL (or the pixel buffer from the video), etc.)

**CGImage** = The bitmap image in raw

Yes, sometimes a UIImage can appear without the cg. But why not query for the 'recipe'
instead and try create a CG yourself?
You'll a context and a call to 'createCGImage' :

```
if let cg = pickedImage!.cgImage {
    // you've got a CG :)
} else {
    // make CG yourself from CIImage
    if let ci = pickedImage!.ciImage {
        let context = CIContext()
        guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ci, from: ci.extent) else { return }
        let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)    
    }
}
```